# Converting array of digits to a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, parseint

Given the following strings array:

```
["9", "3", "3", "3", "8", "5", "2", "7", "0", "2", "2", "2", "7", "9", "8", "7"]
```

I've written this reduce code, trying to convert the array to a number (without using any built in parsers).

```
d.reduce((res,n,idx)=>{
   res *= 10;
   res += n.charCodeAt(0) - 48;
   console.log(res);
   return res;
},0);
```

Here is the log:

```
9
93
933
9333
93338
933385
9333852
93338527
933385270
9333852702
93338527022
933385270222
9333852702227
93338527022279
933385270222798
9333852702227988
```

**933385270222798(8) <-- Should be 7**

I've noticed that `9333852702227980 + 7 = 9333852702227988`

The code goes of when the number is big, I'm guessing I'm out of safe Integer bounds. How can I fix this?

Comment: As you guessed, you've exceeded the range of [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), which is `9007199254740991` or `(2**53)-1`, so you're losing precision.

Comment: `var num = nums.reduce((p,c) => 10*p + +c);` yet as mentioned by @squint if the sum exceeds the maximum safe integer limit then the result is no more safe.

Comment: So, is it possible to parse larger the MAX_SAFE_INTEGER numbers in JS?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Do you necessarily need a number and not a string? What do you consider a "built in parser"?

Comment: What about https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer ... how does it work?

Comment: @RoniGadot - If you want to stay within JavaScript native types, then no, you will always lose precision. But there are many arbitrary-precision integer packages available. You would either have to use one or design one.

Comment: You could begin by dividing the number by some power of 10 and then do all your calculations and finally convert the number back to a string and remove the decimal before displaying it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look into arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic packages, for example [Big Numbers](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html), [Big](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/), or [Crunch](http://crunch.js.org/). They should give you some ideas on how to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convertArrayToNumber(arr) {
    let result = ""
    for (el of arr) {
        result += el
    }
    return result
}

let yourArray = ["9", "3", "3", "3", "8", "5", "2", "7", "0", "2", "2", "2", "7", "9", "8", "7"]
Number(convertArrayToNumber(yourArray))
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert to a **string**, then use **replaceAll** function to replace the commas on the resulting string:

```js
const arr = ["9", "3", "3", "3", "8", "5", "2", "7", "0", "2", "2", "2", "7", "9", "8", "7"]
const no = (arr.toString()).replaceAll(',','');
console.log("result: ", no)
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
var arr = ["9", "3", "3", "3", "8", "5", "2", "7", "0", "2", "2", "2", "7", "9", "8", "7"];
var num = 0;

for (a = arr.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
  num += arr[a] * Math.pow(10, (arr.length - 1) - a);
}

Number.prototype.add = function(x) {
  var out = 0;
  for (a = arr.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
    out += (arr[a] * 1 + (x[(arr.length - 1) - a] || 0) * 1) * Math.pow(10, (arr.length - 1) - a);
  }
  return out;
}

console.log(num);
console.log(num.add('7'));
```

Comment: `Number` is also a builtin parser. Your first result log is showing the same loss of precision.

Comment: Yes, I've been toying around with your example since it almost seems to give an expected result. I just don't know that it can actually be done since integers are represented only with 53 bits, so I don't know how one could not lose precision. But if there's some trick, it'll be really interesting.

Comment: My idea is to perform the addition at the level of each digit to avoid exceeding the safe integer range.

Comment: Yes, but ultimately you'll need to store them together and that resulting number will exceed a 53 bit range. But if there's some trick to get the JS engine to let you "borrow" some bits outside that range, that would be really slick. I doubt it's possible, but who knows.